# UITableView shows sometimes a separating line between the cells, on the iPhone, not on the iPad

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `tableView` with dynamic `tableViewCells`, and the separator property is set to `none`.
Each cell has 3 `subviews`, called here *backgroundViews*, of the cell height, placed with equal width side by side. They present a background color.
Each of these *backgroundViews* has an `imageView` as ist own `subview`. The `imageView` has the same size as its *backgroundView*.
The `tableViewCell` and its subviews are layed out by **autolayout**, i.e. the `imageViews` have margins of 0 to their *backgroundView*, and the 3 *backgroundViews* have margins of 0 to the `tableViewCell` top and bottom, the left *backgroundView* has a margin of 0 to the left edge of the cell, the right *backgroundView* has a margin of 0 to the right cell edge, and all 3 *backgroundViews* have equal widths.

[image]

In the simplest case, the `image` property of the `imageViews` is `nil`, so that the colored background of the *backgroundViews* is visible.
When I run the app on an iPad (simulator or device), everything looks fine.
When I run it **on an iPhone** (simulator or device), **there are sometimes little separating lines between some of the cells**, maybe 1 point high (in the screenshot below after the 2nd and the 5th cell).
[image]
This separating line is not related to the *backgroundViews*, since these have a background color, and the separating line is white. It is neither related to the `tableViewCell`, nor the `contentView`, since both have a clear background color. It is neither related to the `tableView` itself, since its background color is set to black.
I have no idea where this separating line comes from, nor why it shows up only on the iPhone, and not of the iPad. 
Any suggestion how I could get rid of these annoying lines is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the following:
I divided the `tableViewCell` width by 3, and set the `tableView`'s `rowHeight` property to the same value, to get 3 squares side by side.
On the iPad, the row height was 768/3 = 256, an integer value.
On the iPhone, the row height was 320/3 = 106.66666666666667, a fractional value. Thus, the row height could not be mapped 1:1 to the screen points.
When I rounded the row height by

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = ceil(fieldWidth);
```

the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer didn't work for me. However, setting `clipsToBounds` property on cells helped

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier( ... )
    ...
    cell.clipsToBounds = true
}
```